# Sorting and comparing HoHoA on value

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I have a HoHoA set up as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %experiment = (
    'gene1' =>  {
                       'condition2' => ['XLOC_000347','80', '0.5'],
                       'condition3' => ['XLOC_000100', '50', '0.2']
                   },
    'gene2'   =>  {
                       'condition1' => ['XLOC_025437', '100', '0.018'],
                       'condition2' => ['XLOC_000322', '77', '0.22'],
                       'condition3' => ['XLOC_001000', '43', '0.02']
                   },
    'gene3'   =>  {
                      'condition1' => ['XLOC_025437', '100', '0.018'],
                      'condition3' => ['XLOC_001045', '23', '0.0001']
                   },
    'gene4'   =>  {
                      'condition3' => ['XLOC_091345', '93', '0.005']
                   }

);
```

I'm trying to find all 'genes' that overlap in at least 2 conditions, and, for each gene, print out the condition with the lowest value (e.g. q_value). I then want to sort by this value. Here is my code so far:

Loop through 1st key, to find all keys that appear in at least 2 of the 2nd key.

```
my(%overlap, %condition_name);
my ($xloc, $q_val, $percentage, %seen);

for my $gene (sort keys %experiment) { 
    for my $condition (sort keys %{$experiment{$gene}}) {
        $condition_name{$condition} = 1;
        $seen{$gene}++; # Counts for each occurrence of gene 
        $overlap{$gene} = 1 if $seen{$gene} > 1;
    }
}
```

For each overlapping instance, print out each condition (key2) in which key1 is found, and  associated values:

```
my @cond_name = keys %condition_name;
foreach my $gene (keys %overlap){ 
        foreach my $condition (@cond_name){
            next unless exists $experiment{$gene}{$condition};
            ($xloc, $percentage, $q_val) = @{$experiment{$gene}{$condition}};
            print "$condition\t$gene\t$xloc\t$q_val\t$percentage\n";
        }
        print "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
condition3  gene3   XLOC_001045 0.0001  23
condition1  gene3   XLOC_025437 0.018   100

condition3  gene1   XLOC_000100 0.2 50
condition2  gene1   XLOC_000347 0.5 80

condition3  gene2   XLOC_001000 0.02    43
condition1  gene2   XLOC_025437 0.018   100
condition2  gene2   XLOC_000322 0.22    77
```

I'm trying to change the output in two ways:

- For each overlapping instance of key1, compare each of the second keys based on one of their values. For example, for `gene 1`, I would want to compare the first value for `condition3` and `condition2` (q_value) and keep only the lowest value.

Desired output:

```
condition3  gene3   XLOC_001045 0.0001  23    
condition3  gene1   XLOC_000100 0.2 50
condition1  gene2   XLOC_025437 0.018   100
```

- Secondly, I would like to sort this by the same value I select on (q_value) to give:

Desired final output (see update below):

```
condition3  gene3   XLOC_001045 0.0001  23
condition1  gene2   XLOC_025437 0.018   100
condition3  gene1   XLOC_000100 0.2 50
```

***Update:16.9.13***

I have started a bounty on this question as the answer (although good) does not achieve exactly what I was hoping for. If any clarification in the question is required please let me know...

I also have a slight change in my final desired output: 
As above, I want to compare each condition on one of the values, and sort the genes based on that value. Ideally though, I want to output each condition (and sort internally on the same value) for each sorted gene as such:

```
condition3  gene3   XLOC_001045 0.0001  23 # Lowest q_value
condition1  gene3   XLOC_025437 0.018   100 # Other condition(s) for the gene with lowest q_value...

condition1  gene2   XLOC_025437 0.018   100 # For each gene, rank by q_value
condition3  gene2   XLOC_001000 0.02    43
condition2  gene2   XLOC_000322 0.22    77

condition3  gene1   XLOC_000100 0.2 50
condition2  gene1   XLOC_000347 0.5 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this code, which I simplified as much as possible. I started with the original code you posted, I hope I didn't miss any of the initial round of changes. Commented inline:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %experiment = (
    'gene1' =>  {
                       'condition2' => ['XLOC_000347','80', '0.5'],
                       'condition3' => ['XLOC_000100', '50', '0.2']
                   },
    'gene2'   =>  {
                       'condition1' => ['XLOC_025437', '100', '0.018'],
                       'condition2' => ['XLOC_000322', '77', '0.22'],
                       'condition3' => ['XLOC_001000', '43', '0.02']
                   },
    'gene3'   =>  {
                      'condition1' => ['XLOC_025437', '100', '0.018'],
                      'condition3' => ['XLOC_001045', '23', '0.0001']
                   },
    'gene4'   =>  {
                      'condition3' => ['XLOC_091345', '93', '0.005']
                   }

);
```

I moved a few of your `my` declarations around to where they were needed. I also created the `qvals` hash, which I use instead of your `overlap` hash. It will contain the smallest qval for each gene for easy sorting.

```
my (%qvals, %seen);

for my $gene (sort keys %experiment) { 
    for my $condition (sort keys %{$experiment{$gene}}) {
        $seen{$gene}++; # Counts for each occurrence of gene
```

So now we need to build our qvals hash. This is going to be our first (outer) sort key for the printout. The first condition for each gene, we'll save that gene's qvalue. For subsequent conditions, if we find a smaller qvalue, we save that one instead.

```
        if ((not exists $qvals{$gene}) || # First time we've seen this gene, OR
            ($qvals{$gene} > $experiment{$gene}{$condition}[2])) { # Has a smaller q value
            $qvals{$gene} = $experiment{$gene}{$condition}[2];
        }
    }
}
```

You may not be familiar with this sort syntax. The thing in braces `{}` is a 'sort block'. You can learn a lot more than I can explain by typing `perldoc sort` into google or your Linux console - it allows you to do very complicated things, but here all we use it for is to sort on something other than the data we're sorting. Here, we sort the genes (`keys %qvals`) on their minimum qvalue `$qvals{$a}`. `$a` and `$b` are automatically used by `sort`, don't worry about declaring them, and `<=>` is the spaceship operator - it's like a super-comparison that returns `0` if the operands are equal, `-1` if the left operator is smaller, and `+1` if the left operator is larger. Basically, if you don't specify a sort block, sort will use `{$a <=> $b}` by default.

```
foreach my $gene (sort {$qvals{$a} <=> $qvals{$b}} keys %qvals) { # Sort the genes on ascending minimum q-val 
    if ($seen{$gene} == 1) {next;} # Skip gene if it only has one condition
    foreach my $condition (sort # Sort conditions on ascending q-val
```

Another complex sort, this time for the conditions of each gene - we sort the conditions (`keys $experiment{$gene}`) on the q-value of that condition for that gene (`$experiment{$gene}{$a}[2]`).

```
                {$experiment{$gene}{$a}[2] <=> $experiment{$gene}{$b}[2]}
                keys $experiment{$gene} ) { 
        next unless exists $experiment{$gene}{$condition};
        my ($xloc, $percentage, $q_val) = @{$experiment{$gene}{$condition}};
        print "$condition\t$gene\t$xloc\t$q_val\t$percentage\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

I get the following output:

```
condition3      gene3   XLOC_001045     0.0001  23
condition1      gene3   XLOC_025437     0.018   100

condition1      gene2   XLOC_025437     0.018   100
condition3      gene2   XLOC_001000     0.02    43
condition2      gene2   XLOC_000322     0.22    77

condition3      gene1   XLOC_000100     0.2     50
condition2      gene1   XLOC_000347     0.5     80
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when I run it I get the following error: `Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash or array (not hash element)` - on the line containing: `foreach my $condition (sort {$experiment{$gene}{$a}[2] <=> $experiment{$gene}{$b}[2]} keys $experiment{$gene} ) {`

Comment: Worked on my platform, but some older Perls don't allow you to pass a hashref into `keys`. You may have to say `keys %{$experiment{$gene}}`.

Comment: This is really tidy. It's particularly good as it builds on my existing code - and is therefore easy for me to tweak - and does exactly what I wanted. I'll play around with it on my real data...

Comment: Just looking over this again. I was hoping you'd be able to explain how this part works: `if ((not exists $qvals{$gene}) || ($qvals{$gene} > $experiment{$gene}{$condition}[2])) { 
            $qvals{$gene} = $experiment{$gene}{$condition}[2];`

Comment: How is it possible to compare `$qvals{$gene}` (which is a gene name) on q_value with `$experiment{$gene}{$condition}[2]` which is a value?

Comment: Negative. `%qvals` is a hash we are making, the value is a number, coresponding with the q-value. We want the maximum q-value to be stored in `%qvals`, so we iterate over each gene and condition. If it's the first time we've seen the gene, then we store that condition's q-value in the hash. Otherwise, we only store this condition's q-value if it exceeds the q-value that is already in the hash. We then use this hash (of the highest q-value for each gene) to sort the genes, and we use `%$experiment{$gene}` to sort the conditions within each gene.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is over complicated. To get a list of genes that have two or more conditions, use grep:

```
my @genes = grep { keys %{$experiment{$_}} >= 2 } keys %experiment;
```

Next we need to sort the genes on their minimum q_value. The easiest way to do this (although by far not the most efficient way) is to first find the minimum for each gene and stuff that into a hash:

```
use List::Util qw(min);

my %minimum;
foreach my $gene (@genes) {
    my @q_vals;
    push @q_vals, $experiment{$gene}{$_}[2] for keys %{$experiment{$gene}};
    $minimum{$gene} = min @q_vals;
}
```

When we've gotten all the minimum values, we can sort them:

```
@genes = sort { $minimum{$a} <=> $minimum{$b} } keys %minimum;
```

Now we just need to sort the conditions in each gene and print out the values:

```
foreach my $gene (@genes) {

    # Sort conditions on the "2th" field (counting from 0)
    my @conditions = sort { $experiment{$gene}{$a}[2] <=> $experiment{$gene}{$b}[2] } keys %{$experiment{$gene}};

    foreach my $condition (@conditions) {
        my ($xloc, $percentage, $q_val) = @{$experiment{$gene}{$condition}};
        print "$condition\t$gene\t$xloc\t$q_val\t$percentage\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

**Updated output:**

```
condition3  gene3   XLOC_001045 0.0001  23
condition1  gene3   XLOC_025437 0.018   100

condition1  gene2   XLOC_025437 0.018   100
condition3  gene2   XLOC_001000 0.02    43
condition2  gene2   XLOC_000322 0.22    77

condition3  gene1   XLOC_000100 0.2 50
condition2  gene1   XLOC_000347 0.5 80
```

This is not a very efficient method, because we're traversing our hash multiple times. You might want to consider changing your data structure to something a little more manageable.

Comment: OK great - thanks! This looks like a very elegant solution. However, I only want to sort by q_value, not by gene name - how could I amend for this?

Comment: @FlyingFrog Remove the `sort` from the outer `foreach` loop.

Comment: That's what I tried. However, while the internal conditions are sorted correctly, the genes are not globally sorted by q_value. Compare your output with my desired output to see what I mean...

Comment: @FlyingFrog They aren't globally sorted in your desired output either: the last four q_values you have are 0.02, 0.22, 0.2, and 0.5. Last I checked, 0.22 > 0.2

Comment: @FlyingFrog Okay, I think I understand, you want to sort the conditions inside each gene by q_value, and to sort the genes by minimum q_value?

Comment: I want to have the condition/gene with the lowest q_vlaue at the top, and all other conditions for that gene associated with it, then, I want the condition/gene with the second lowest q value and all other conditions for that gene associated with it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37610/discussion-between-thissuitisblacknot-and-flyingfrog)

Answer (score 1):

Construct another HoH instead of printing. Iterate over that at the end to decide what to print.

So at the top, add this:

```
my %lowest;
my $sortkey='q_val';
```

In the middle, make this edit:

```
foreach my $condition (@cond_name){
    next unless exists $experiment{$gene}{$condition};
    ## ($xloc, $percentage, $q_val) = @{$experiment{$gene}{$condition}};
    ## print "$condition\t$gene\t$xloc\t$q_val\t$percentage\n";

    my %cond;
    @cond{ qw( xloc percentage q_val ) } = @{$experiment{$gene}{$condition}};
    # >= may also be appropriate
    if (!defined($lowest{$gene}) or $lowest{$gene}{$sortkey} > $cond{$sortkey}) {  
        @cond{ qw( condition gene ) } = ($condition, $gene); # useful at print time
        $lowest{$gene} = \%cond
    }
}
## print "\n";
```

And at the end:

```
# NB: <=> is for numeric comparison. Use cmp for non-numeric keys.
for my $gene (sort { $lowest{$a}{$sortkey} <=> $lowest{$b}{$sortkey} } keys %lowest) {
    local ($, , $\)=("\t","\n");
    print @{$lowest{$gene}}{qw( condition gene xloc q_val percentage )};
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant - thanks. I need to digest exactly what's going on here, but it looks like a great solution!

Comment: `@cond{ qw( ... ) } = ...` Converting array to a hash. This is not neccessary: it's fine to say `$sortkey=2` and sort on array index. But building a result set for later display is a common idiom and the creation/use usually happen far apart. It's nice to have names attached to the fields.

`@cond{ qw( condition gene ) } = ...` Attaching identity fields to the hash allows you to restructure results later, w/o digging up parent key-names.

Storage space is one reason to NOT use a hash. If your resultset is huge, the hashes take >2x space of lists (in this example, anyway).

Comment: `$,` is the field separator displayed when printing a list.  `$\ ` is the record separator.  local() constrains the assignment to that block; they revert to previous values outside of the block.  It's the same as `print join("\t", @{...}{...}),"\n"`.

Comment: This actually isn't working as I thought. The output I get does not necessarily correspond to the condition with the lowest q-value for each gene...

Comment: Can you give an example?   The output of my test program matches your final output

Comment: See update. Your code worked on my example but on trying it on my real data, I found that it produced unexpected results. However, it's possible that some of the surrounding code I was using (to achieve the updated objective) affected the output...

Answer (score 0):

```
use 5.10.0;
$, = "\t";
do {
    my ( $gene, @conds ) = @$_;
    say( ( $gene, @$_ )[ 1, 0, 2, 4, 3 ] ) for @conds;
    say "";
    }
    for (
    sort { $a->[1][3] <=> $b->[1][3] }
    map {
        my $conds = $experiment{$_};
        [   $_ => sort { $a->[3] <=> $b->[3] }
                map { [ $_, @{ $conds->{$_} } ] }
                keys %$conds
        ]
    } grep { keys %{ $experiment{$_} } > 1 } keys %experiment
    );
```

Will make output:

```
condition3      gene3   XLOC_001045     0.0001  23
condition1      gene3   XLOC_025437     0.018   100

condition1      gene2   XLOC_025437     0.018   100
condition3      gene2   XLOC_001000     0.02    43
condition2      gene2   XLOC_000322     0.22    77

condition3      gene1   XLOC_000100     0.2     50
condition2      gene1   XLOC_000347     0.5     80
```

Or

```
use 5.10.0;
$, = "\t";
say @$_[ 1, 0, 2, 4, 3 ]
    for (
    map {
        my ( $gene, @conds ) = @$_;
        map { [ $gene, @$_ ] } @conds
    }
    sort { $a->[1][3] <=> $b->[1][3] }
    map {
        my $conds = $experiment{$_};
        [   $_ => sort { $a->[3] <=> $b->[3] }
                map { [ $_, @{ $conds->{$_} } ] }
                keys %$conds
        ]
    } grep { keys %{ $experiment{$_} } > 1 } keys %experiment
    );
```

Will make output:

```
condition3      gene3   XLOC_001045     0.0001  23
condition1      gene3   XLOC_025437     0.018   100
condition1      gene2   XLOC_025437     0.018   100
condition3      gene2   XLOC_001000     0.02    43
condition2      gene2   XLOC_000322     0.22    77
condition3      gene1   XLOC_000100     0.2     50
condition2      gene1   XLOC_000347     0.5     80
```